# vue y axios no me trae los datos

Tags: vue.js, axios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
estoy utilizando vue con axios por primera vez y no me trae los datos como quisiera, me los muestra tipo:
estoy utilizando vue con axios por primera vez y no me trae los datos como quisiera, me los muestra tipo:
estoy utilizando vue con axios por primera vez y no me trae los datos como quisiera, me los muestra tipo:

```
  {{item.post_date}}
    {{item.post_title}}
    {{item.post_description}}
```

como se puede apreciar en la imagen.
¿alguna idea de que puede ser?

aquí el codigo que estoy utilizando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
if (document.getElementById("noticias")) {

var VuePostList = new Vue({
    el: '#noticias',
    data() {
        return {
            filtro: { },
            items: [],
            endpoint: vuecfg.endpoint + 'noticias',
            paginas: [1],
            numpagina: 1
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.reset();
        this.loadItems();
    },
    methods: {
        reset: function() {
            this.filtro = {
                numpagina: 1,
                filtro: ''
            };
        },
        Paginacion: function (num) {
            if(num < 1) num = 1;
            if(num > this.paginas.length) num = this.paginas.length;
            this.numpagina = num;
            this.filtro.numpagina = num;
            this.loadItems();
        },
        loadItems: function () {
            axios
                .post(this.endpoint, this.filtro)
                .then(response => {
                    this.items = response.data.items;
                    this.paginas = response.data.paginas;
                })
        }
    }
})

}; //aparte utilizo 

var urlapi = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/es/api/'; var vuecfg = {}; vuecfg.endpoint = urlapi;
```

Comment: Añade todo el código (la parte de axios) para poder revisar todo y darte una respuesta más acertada.

Comment: Si puedes, añade también qué debería aparecer y qué aparece en la parte donde dices que falla.

Comment: Vale, una cosa, ¿estás con un proyecto Vue o estás en un HTML básico e importando el script de Vue? Si es lo primero, no sé qué puede ser, si es lo segundo, parece que no se está importando bien el script de VueJS y es por eso que no se crean bien dichos parámetros.